# critical files to be monitored by file integrity monitoring solutions in active directory servers

Tags: active-directory, monitoring, microsoft

We are implementing file integrity solution on Microsoft active directory servers,
I need to know the critical paths(files and folders and registry keys) that need to be monitored for any change or the paths which are targeted by common malwares and attacks.

Comment: I think you may find this link of value https://www.andreafortuna.org/2017/07/06/malware-persistence-techniques/ it is basically a list of registry keys malware is using for persistence and also some other novel techniques.

Comment: thanks alot for this nice article but what i needs is specific paths or reg keys related to active directory.

Comment: Ok not sure what your trying to achieve here as those particular registry keys or files/folders probably change all the time. Why would i monitor the C:\Users when an attacker is adding a user to AD. How can you stop an attack if you don't know the techniques the attackers are using. This page is priceless when it comes to security within AD. https://adsecurity.org/?page_id=4031